# Java KeyListener in inner class doesn't get the event for some reason

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a class that has a KeyListener class nested into it, but the event doesn't seem to register. I am pretty new to Java, so i might be doing something completely wrong...

This is the code:

```
    public class CaesarFrame extends JFrame{
        ...
        private JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField(20);
        ...
        jtf1.addKeyListener(this.new InputFieldKeyListener());
        ...
        class InputFieldKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 4 lines of code doesn't help us. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: worksforme - the problem is somewhere hidden behind the dots :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do you need `this.new ...` when adding the `KeyListener`? Can you try omitting `this.` and just putting:

```
jtf1.addKeyListener(new InputFieldKeyListener());
```

Also, not sure what you're trying to do precisely, but make sure you're using the proper event. Your JTextField might be generating `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` events when you think it will be `keyTyped`.

I would override those two additional events the same way you did `keyTyped`, and see what output you get. That might be all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The two other events don't fire either, and omitting the `this` doesn't seem to change it. I have a JButton in there with a similarly declared ActionListener, and that works well, so its a bit odd, but I must be overlooking something...

Comment: (1) *Immediately* after the line adding the KeyListener, if you call `System.out.println(jtf1.getKeyListeners().length)` does it print something other than `0`, and/or do you get a NullPointerException? (2) After adding the KeyListener, are you perhaps accidentally re-declaring `jtf1`, and therefore creating a new object, with an empty set of KeyListeners?

Answer (score 2):

"To fire keyboard events, a component *must* have the keyboard focus."—[*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). Alternatively, consider key bindings, examples of which may be found in the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883422/how-do-i-scroll-jscrollpane-viewport-containing-a-jpanel-to-a-specific-location/7883568#7883568).