# How do I scroll JScrollPane viewport containing a JPanel to a specific location

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, viewport

I am trying to create a large game board that only part of it will be visible in the viewport and would like to be able to move the viewport around using the arrow keys to see the whole board.  Right now I have a JScrollPane that contains a JPanel that will have Images and text and other stuff, but those are irrelevant.  Right now I have an ImageIcon at the same size as the JPanel as a background and I would like to have an option to move the viewport around by using keys, and not have any visible scrollbars. 
I have tried calling getViewPort().setViewPosition() followed by revalidate() on the JPanel and the JScrollPane.  But it still does not work.  My code is below

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Game extends JPanel {

    JPanel game = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(game);
    JLabel grass = new JLabel();

    private KeyListener keys = new KeyListener() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("Down");
                scrollPane.getViewport()

            } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                System.out.println("up");
            }
            revalidate();
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    };

public void createGame(int turns) {

        int gameWidth = 1800;
        int gameHeight = 1600;

        int viewPortWidth = 800;
        int viewPortHeight = 600;

        //setLayout(null);
        setSize(new Dimension(viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight));

        game.setLayout(null);
        game.setSize(new Dimension(gameWidth, gameHeight));

        //add the background image
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("Grass.png");
        grass.setIcon(background);
        grass.setBounds(0,0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        game.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        game.add(grass);
        game.setBounds(0,0, gameWidth, gameHeight);

        //key listener
        game.addKeyListener(keys);

        //add(game);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight));

        add(scrollPane);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an example that uses [`scrollRectToVisible()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818387/jscrollpane-with-multiple-jtextareas/7820703#7820703) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). You should be able to adapt it to your usage.

As an aside, consider using [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887296/how-to-make-an-image-move-while-listening-to-a-keypress-in-java/6887628#6887628) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201509/mousemotionlistener-in-java-swing-using-it-with-components-inside-components-et/7203419#7203419).

Answer (score 4):

KeyEvents only go to components that have focus. By default a `JPanel` does not have focus so it does not receive `KeyEvent`s. You can make a panel focusable by invoking the [`setFocusable()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29) method on the panel.

Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). They can be set up to work even if the component doesn't have focus.

Using [`setViewPosition()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setViewPosition%28java.awt.Point%29) should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the KeyEvent code, i already have that working.  But when it comes to the viewport position, the setViewPosition() doesn't seem to work.  I have even tried calling revalidate and repaint just in case.  It still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I had the layout of the Panel being viewed as null and not as a BorderLayout, unfortunately this means that I have to have the scroll bars.

I am currently finding a way to hide the scrollbars and keep the functionality